# Can a thyratron be used as a current booster?

Tags: vacuum-tube

I haven't been able to find any decent equations that describe the thyratron cathode-plate current as a function of the anode and grid voltage differences. But in particular, if a thyratron is operated at or above the ignition voltage, how much current in relation to the cathode potential will flow into it and can it be used to draw in more current?

Answer (score 1):

According to Perkin-Elmer:

> Conduction:
>   Once the commutation interval
>   has ended, a typical hydrogen
>   thyratron will conduct with nearly
>   constant voltage drop on the
>   order of 100 volts regardless of
>   the current through the tube

This applies to a typical 32kV 20kA deuterium-filled hydrogen thyratron (HY-3202).